# Issue with & in a string submitted with $_GET

Tags: php, string, url, get

I'm building an "away"-page for my website and when a user posted a link to another website, each visitor clicking that link will be redirected first to the away.php file with an info that I am not responsible for the content of the linked website.

The code in away.php to fetch the incoming browser URI is:

```
$goto = $_GET['to'];
```

So far it works, however there's a logical issue with dynamic URIs, in example:

```
www.mydomain.com/away.php?to=http://example.com
```

is working, but dynamic URIs like

```
www.mydomain.com/away.php?to=http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=fvwp&v=j1p0_R8ZLB0
```

aren't working since there is a & included in the linked domain, which will cause ending the $_GET['to'] string to early.

The $goto variable contains only the part until the first &:

```
echo $_GET['to'];
```

===> "http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=fvwp"

I understand why, but looking for a solution since I haven't found it yet on the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `urlencode`:

```
$link = urlencode("http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=fvwp&v=j1p0_R8ZLB0") ;
echo $link;
```

The function will convert url special symbols into appropriate symbols that can carry data.

It will look like this and may be appended to a get parameter:

```
http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Ffeature%3Dfvwp%26v%3Dj1p0_R8ZLB0
```

To get special characters back (for example to output the link) there is a function `urldecode`.

Also function [htmlentities](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) may be useful.

You can test with this:

```
$link = urlencode("http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=fvwp&v=j1p0_R8ZLB0") ;
$redirect = "{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?to={$link}" ;

if (!isset($_GET['to'])){
    header("Location: $redirect") ;
} else {
    echo $_GET['to'];
}
```

**EDIT:**
Ok, I have got a solution for your particular situation.

This solution will work only if:
**Parameter `to` will be last in the query string.**

```
if (preg_match("/to=(.+)/", $redirect, $parts)){ //We got a parameter TO
    echo $parts[1]; //Get everything after TO
}
```

So, `$parts[1]` will be your link.

Comment: It's getting encoded, but the `$_GET['to']` string is still cutted before the &.

Comment: Thank you for your example, however, and correct me please if I am wrong, but you can do it this only if you already know the URI to set it in the $link variable. In my case, I don't know the URI yet, it will be always diffrent and I'm trying to get the posted URI via `$_GET['to']`.

Comment: Its is just not possible without encoding. Can you give me your example?

Comment: I have this URI: `www.mydomain.com/away.php?to=http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=fvwp&v=j1p0_R8ZLB0` and via `$_GET['to']` I need the complete string after the `to=` inclusive the &-parts.

Comment: Ok, it is really strange, but I got it. Let me figure it out.

Comment: It still will not work this new way I guess since you are using preg_match() with the hardcoded URI in your answer. So if using preg_match(), how would you do it with just `$_GET['to']`? Remember: `$_GET['to']` is already incomming not correctly (cutted before the &)

Comment: There is no way to do that.

Comment: I've just updated the question, but as you said, there's perhaps no way to do it this way via $_GET, I will try to find out how some other websites are doing this, I remember I've seen already some "away"-pages. Thanks anyway for your great support in trying to find a solution.

Comment: I've found out using `$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]` to get the full REQUEST string, then using your `preg_match()` code, and I get the exact result I wanted. So I will mark your answer as the correct answer because it forced me into the right direction. Thanks